# Accessing elements of packed symmetric distance matrix

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra, indices

Suppose you have a symmetric distance matrix `A`. For example `A` is `4*4` (the numbers above and on the left of matrix are the indices of elements between which the distance is measured, and we use only the lower triangle):

```
   0   1   2   3  
   _____________
0 |0   0   0   0
1 |a10 0   0   0
2 |a20 a21 0   0
3 |a30 a31 a32 0
```

So, basically, if `A` is `n*n`, we have only `n*(n-1)/2` useful entries. Eliminating zeros on the diagonal, we have the following matrix (similar to what Matlab and R have):

```
A=     0   1   2  
       _________
    1 |a10 0   0
    2 |a20 a21 0
    3 |a30 a31 a32
```

Next, we can efficiently store this matrix in one-dimensional array in packed format having `np = n*(n-1)/2` elements:

```
Ap = {a10, a20, a21, a30, a31, a32}
```

This can speed up many searches (e.g. searching for the pair of closest elements, etc) and save a lot of space (useful when `n` is large)

Accessing the distance between elements `i` and `j` is equivalent to accessing element `j+i(i-1)/2` in packed matrix, i.e. `A[i,j] = Ap[j+i(i-1)/2]` for `i>0, j<n-1, j<i`.

**The question is if we are in the opposite situation, i.e. we have the index of element in packed matrix `Ap`, how do we recover the original two indices:
Given `Ap[x]`, what are `i` and `j` in `A`, such that `Ap[x] = A[i,j]`.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer:

```
i = floor{ (1 + sqrt[1 + 8*x])/2 }
j = x - i
```